# How to structure data for survival analysis with multiple or recurring events in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, survival-analysis, cox-regression

**Background**

I have a project in which I want to compare the amount of time to a health event **Y** between a group of people exposed to a prescription drug treatment **X** and an otherwise similar but treatment-unexposed group (**X**=1 and **X**=0, respectively), all while controlling for a set of covariates **C**.

The data I have to answer this question are health insurance claims (public insurance) in a certain geographical area during a 7-year interval of time.

- Each row in the dataset represents a claim.
- The event **Y** is coded as a diagnostic code, while treatment **X** is coded with a sort of drug serial number used by my country's regulator to identify prescribed drugs.
- Individual patients are coded with unique `ID` numbers.
- Covariates **C** appear in every row in which a patient has a claim. So for instance, their geographical area `geo`, a 3-digit code, will appear in every claim that a certain `ID` has.

Because patients are able to experience multiple events and can appear in the database more than once (with or without eligible exposures or events), I've chosen as my analytic method a Cox model with shared frailty on `ID` to account for within-subject (within-`ID`) correlation. I'm not an expert in survival analysis, though, and I've never done any work with random effects. I'll be analyzing the data in `R`, using its `survival` package and methods.

**The Problem**

I'm not sure how to organize my data to identify the exposed and those with an event. Specifically, do I mark someone who's **X**=1 one *one* claim **X**=1 only on the claim in which their exposures appear, or on *every one of their claims*? (Same applies with outcomes: is someone with an eligible outcome marked **Y**=1 in all their claims, or just in the claim in which the relevant diagnostic code appears?)

To illustrate, here's a dummy dataset representing the first way to go. Let's call this **Option 1**:

```
  ID   | claim_date  | geo  | drug  | exposed | diagnostic_cd |  event  |
-------+-------------+------|-------|---------|---------------|---------|
 001   |  2011-01-30 | 123  |       |    0    |      LZ13     |    1    |
 001   |  2012-04-12 | 123  | D57   |    1    |      SS24     |    0    |
 001   |  2014-06-27 | 123  | A60   |    0    |               |    0    |
 002   |  2017-09-03 | 456  | D57   |    1    |      MN45     |    1    |
 002   |  2018-12-25 | 456  | C08   |    1    |      MN45     |    1    |
```

Here, the exposed are marked as such in the indicator variable `exposed`, and they're only marked in claims in which they have an "exposure event" -- an eligible `drug`. In the case of `ID` 001, that's D57, and for `ID` 002 that's D57 and C08. The same holds for the indicator `event`, which equals 1 when there's an eligible `diagnostic_cd` (LZ13 for `ID` 001, and MN45 for `ID` 002.)

By contrast, here's the other way to go -- **Option 2**:

```
  ID   | claim_date  | geo  | drug  | exposed | diagnostic_cd |  event  |
-------+-------------+------|-------|---------|---------------|---------|
 001   |  2011-01-30 | 123  |       |    1    |      LZ13     |    1    |
 001   |  2012-04-12 | 123  | D57   |    1    |      SS24     |    1    |
 001   |  2014-06-27 | 123  | A60   |    1    |               |    1    |
 002   |  2017-09-03 | 456  | D57   |    1    |      MN45     |    1    |
 002   |  2018-12-25 | 456  | C08   |    1    |      MN45     |    1    |
```

Here, having *any* eligible `drug` or `diagnostic_cd` will mark you `exposed=1` or `event=1` in every row in which your `ID` appears.

My intuition is that `Option 1` is the way to go, but I'm not really able to explain why, and I'm sitting here doubting myself.

Also, this may well be a question that's better suited for CrossValidated, so just let me know if that's the case and I'll post it over there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: if you want to use survival -  what is the time component of the outcome? It looks like you have time varying covariates I would ask this on CrossValidated to get the method down first and then ask a programming question here. But that is just like my opinion man.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Someone will be exposed on `claim_date` X - that'll be a unique claim (a row) - and then they can have the outcome some time later on `claim_date` X+n. Can you clarify?

Comment: that makes sense sorry I didn't put that together. I would say option 1 is closer to correct but unsure how to handle if an event can occur multiple times.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your input Mike!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach is to have an exposure (in this case, a binary exposure) coded 1 or 0 and an event coded 1 or 0. This means option 1 seems to be a more standard approach for modelling any survival analysis dataset.

There are many methods to analyse survival analyses with recurring events, a frailty model is just one of them. One problem with a frailty model is that it assumes all events are equal, which might not always be the case. An excellent tutorial is this paper by DAF Amorim in the *International Journal of Epidemiology* (https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/44/1/324/654595). The authors provide a sample dataset and code in `R`, `Stata` and `SAS`.

What your data seems to be missing is the start date, which is essential for any survival analysis.

Comment: Haven't had time to come back to this post, but I've done a lot of work on the problem since I made it. Just like you said -- "[w]hat your data seems to be missing is the start date, which is essential for any survival analysis" -- I was missing two columns of dates per row denoting `start_time` and `end_time`. The so-called (start, stop] format for survival analyses (I've learned that this is also called 'counting process format' in some quarters). Glad to see your reply just now. I may post my own answer to clarify how I cleared everything up, but I'll mark yours correct. Thanks, Sebastián.